# How to fill quantity values into network in python with networkx?

Tags: python, network-programming, networkx

The main question is, it's possible distribute a determinate quantity in a network satisfying the nodal equations in every node?

e.g: [adding quantity values in a network(mesh) {GIF}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrlvI.gif)

**Nodal equations: Incoming flow (quantity) = Outgoing flow (quantity) for every node.

```
import networkx as nx

inputName = [('D','H'),('G','E'),('B','F'),('H','C'),('E','B'),('C','G'),('H','A'),('C','E'),('A','G'),('D','A'),('F','D')]
quantity = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
resistance = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1]
fan = [0,0,0,0,0,0,2000,0,0,0,0]
def createDirectedGraph(inputName):
    ventilationNetwork = nx.DiGraph()
    i = 0
    for edge in inputName:
        node_from = edge[0]
        node_to = edge[1]
        ventilationNetwork.add_edge(node_from, node_to)
        ventilationNetwork.edges[node_from, node_to]['quantity'] = quantity[i]
        ventilationNetwork.edges[node_from, node_to]['resistance'] = resistance[i]
        ventilationNetwork.edges[node_from, node_to]['fan'] = fan[i]
        i += 1
    return ventilationNetwork
```

I was trying the following:

```
count = 1
for node in ventilationNetwork.nodes:
    if count == 1:
        quantity = 100 # Any quantity != 0
        for node_from in ventilationNetwork.predecessors(node):
            ventilationNetwork.edges[node_from, node]['quantity'] = quantity/(len(list(ventilationNetwork.predecessors(node))))
        for node_to in ventilationNetwork.successors(node):
            ventilationNetwork.edges[node, node_to]['quantity'] = quantity/(len(list(ventilationNetwork.successors(node))))
    else:
        sumQ = 0
        for node_from in ventilationNetwork.predecessors(node):
            sumQ += ventilationNetwork.edges[node_from, node]['quantity']
        ventilationNetwork.edges[node_from, node]['quantity'] = sumQ/(len(list(ventilationNetwork.predecessors(node))))
        for node_to in ventilationNetwork.successors(node):
            sumQ += ventilationNetwork.edges[node, node_to]['quantity']
        ventilationNetwork.edges[node, node_to]['quantity'] = sumQ/(len(list(ventilationNetwork.successors(node))))
    count += 1
```

but it's not working. It's not satisfying the nodal equations.

Any idea how to solve this? With NetworkX or without NetworkX.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are looking at a method from [Flow](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/flow.html) could help you, e.g. [`min_cost_flow`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.min_cost_flow.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.min_cost_flow). For that you would need to define the demand (positive or negative) of each node, and the capacity of each edge.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for that.
Although what I'm looking for is very similar.